# How to do URL rewriting of static page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm new to URlRewriting and I've been having some problems rewriting my URLs. I done rewriting for dynamic urls 
like

```
www.mysite.com/page.php?id=4
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/4
```

But I have problem in static page url rewriting ..

```
www.mysite.com/page.php
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/page
```

I google alot but not find sutable answer..  Please help me.....

I am using these patterns

```
RewriteRule ^flight-bookings /flight-bookings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^flight-bookings$ /flight-bookings.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^flight-bookings flight-bookings.php [L]
```

But no one work I always got 404 page not found.. while

```
www.mysite.com/flight-bookings.php
```

working perfectly

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy

Comment: Start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyi thank To all of you for help me..
finally I found the issue...

I dont know the logic is write is right or wrong but is work on my senerio ..

I try to do url rewrite of "/flight-booking **s.php**" to /flight-booking **s**

Here the URL and REWRITED URL was same

But when I try "/flight-booking **.php**" to /flight-booking **s** 
It workes...

Conclusion: In static page's URL rewrite name of page and patteren should be distinct "I distinguish it by **'s'** "

Actual URL:-

```
www.mysite.com/flight-booking.php
```

After rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/flight-bookings
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^page page.php [L]
```

Comment: should probably have `[QSA,L]` at the end so query strings are added as well, ie `page?mystuff=goeshere`

Comment: it's up to him to extend the rule as far as he likes if it is mapping /page to page.php which i understood is the question here.

Comment: I am using these patterns  
`RewriteRule ^flight-bookings /flight-bookings.php [L]`
`RewriteRule ^flight-bookings$ /flight-bookings.php [L]`
`RewriteRule ^flight-bookings flight-bookings.php [L]`

But no one work
I always got 404 page not found..  
while 
`www.mysite.com/flight-bookings.php` 
working perfectly

Comment: you may have a rule before these ones that verifies the url and rewrites it to something else. can you post the entire htaccess file?

Comment: @Udan My dynamic url rewriting is working fine but this static url's rewriting is not working...